# Link image hover with tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

How can i add hover color in image link??

```
<a class="pink-light hover:fill-primary-color" href="{{ $youtube }}">
   <img src="/img/YouTube.png">
</a>
```

Comment: hover not wirking

Comment: What do you want to add exactly ? Background color ? Filter ? What did you tried so far ?

Comment: i want to change backgroung (fill color) in hover

Comment: I found the solution.I change img from png to svg .Its work now
thanks